# Отловить закрытие приложения

Tags: java, android

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: надо отловить запуск и закрытие моего приложения. При запуске должен создаваться поток (ну с этим у меня проблем нет), а при остановке должен один раз вызваться метод `stopped`.

С запуском разобрался - создал класс-наследник (`Application`), в `onCreate` назначил запуск потока. А с закрытием приложения я зашёл в тупик. Дело в том, что моё приложение содержит много активити, которые открываются на протяжении работы приложения, так что в `onStop` каждой активити вызывать `stopped` не вариант, а в `Application` переопределить метод `onStop` нельзя (так как его нет).

Вопрос таков: "Можно ли отловить полное закрытие **приложения** (а не определённой активити) и как?".

Answer (score 1):

Мне вот гугл на запрос:

> receive application stop event android

выдал [вот это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19135943/3212712). Судя по всему, вам подойдёт второй вариант из ответа. Если кратко - надо в Application задать сеттер и геттер для флага **ЗАПУЩЕНО** и обновлять его из каждой активити в onResume() и onPause().

```
class BaseActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((MyAppContext)getApplication()).setIsAppRunning(true);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    ((MyAppContext)getApplication()).setIsAppRunning(false);
    super.onPause();
}
}
```

Таким образом, если все активити закрыты, будет false;
А в Apllication таймером следить за флагом и делать чего-нибудь. Код из ссылки:

```
public class MyAppContext extends Application {

public boolean isAppRunning = true;
public final int timerRate = 500;    // Execute timer task every 500mS

public void setIsAppRunning(boolean v){
  isAppRunning = v;
}

public boolean isAppRunning(){
  return isAppRunning;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  Timer mTimer = new Timer();

  mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        if(isAppRunning) startSesionTracking();
        else stopSesionTracking();
     }
  }, 0, REFRESH_TIME);
}

private void startSesionTracking () { ... };
private void stopSesionTracking () { ... };

}
```